# Insert date and time into table as (sysdate+1) with specific time

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-update

I want to insert data and time into a SQL database field as (sysdate+1) with specific time.

Example:
If current date/time is 05/03/2023 20:05:05 , the data/time should be inserted as 06/03/2023 00:30:00.
So sysdate+1 for fixed time 00:30:00.

Is there any way to do that?

Database:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.8.0

```
update table set dvalid = trunc(sysdate+1);
```

This gives the (sysdate+1), but I want to set the time to exactly 00:30:00.

```
to_date('06-03-2023 00:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'); --> format
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (sysdate, trunc and to_date are all product specific.)

Comment: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update table set dvalid = (trunc(sysdate+1)+1/48);
```

This will work for the `DATE` data type, which tracks a full day as a differential of "1". An hour interval is therefore "1/24" and a 30 minute interval is "1/48". This will *not* work for a `TIMESTAMP` data type, which uses a different internal format and requires that you use an `interval` modifier:

```
(trunc(systimestamp) + interval '1' day + interval '30' minute)
```

Comment: You can combine the interval literals as `TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1 00:30:00' DAY TO SECOND`.

Comment: update table set dvalid = (trunc(sysdate+1)+1/48); --> this worked perfectly. Thank you.